# Using SQL Server with dotnet core 6.0 in a Windows Service

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, windows-services

I am trying to add SQL Server connections to a new Windows Service. All the documentation indicates that we add

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>
```

in `Program.cs`.

However a Windows service (`IHost`) does not show the `AddDbContext` method in services. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Already been here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

and here: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/03/18/net-6-connect-to-sql-server-with-entity-framework-core @JasonWatmore

and similar....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AddDbContext instead of AddDbContact.
Try it; `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>();`

Also make sure you have these packages installed;

> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 6.0.8
>
> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 6.0.8

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the wrong dependency. You need to add this dependency

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Comment: sorry for the (obvious) type-o everyone. When I start typing services.AddD .... with nother further, the is no AddDbContext to be found.